# Multiplying Subqueries in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, multiplication

It's been a while since I started to learn pgsql and I'm trying to work on my first project (just to test myself) and I've been trying to make this work.

```
SELECT ((SELECT to_number(g.grade, '9D99') AS numgrade
           FROM grade g, registration r
           WHERE g.grade_id=r.grade_id 
            AND g.grade!='INC'
            AND g.grade!='INP'
            AND g.grade!='W'
            AND g.grade!='DRP')*(SELECT s.subjunits
                         FROM subject s, registration r
                         WHERE s.subjcode=r.subjcode)) AS product
FROM subject s, registration r;
```

So, what I want to do is multiply the column `grade` (*just in case you didn't notice,* column `grade` is a `character` which is why I put `to_char()`) from table `registration` and column `subjunits` from table `subject`.

I kind of figured out that Postgres doesn't allow multiplying of multiple rows or maybe it doesn't allow returning of multiple rows. Either way I still wanted to know if there's another way getting the product of the rows that I have selected?

Putting every single subject in the `WHERE` clause is very inconvenient.

Comment: In future questions, please always show the **exact text** of any error message, along with your PostgreSQL version (`select version()`), and where possible sample data and table definitions. You might also want to check out http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT (to_number(g.grade, '9D99') * s.subjunits) AS product
  FROM grade g, registration r, subject s
  WHERE g.grade_id = r.grade_id 
    AND g.grade NOT IN ('INC', 'INP', 'W', 'DRP')
    AND s.subjcode = r.subjcode;
```

You probably want to add a student number in your select list. Also, if your g.grade types are many more then the four here excluded, add a column for that; if there are fewer than four, then reverse the clause: `AND g.grade IN (...)`.

Comment: Re `IN` vs `NOT IN` optimizations: It can actually be a lot faster to write it as a join on a `VALUES` clause if you have lots of values to filter on. For `NOT IN` you use a left anti-join; for `IN` you use an inner join. (But that's rather more advanced SQL than the original poster will want to tackle at this point).

Comment: Nicely deduced from a question that lacks explicit schema definitions, btw, +1

Comment: I thought using some subqueries are necessary. Thanks. It turns out that I've been making things complicated. I'm actually trying to calculate the GPA. I already tried your code and it works like a charm.

so this query worked 

`SELECT r.studid, (SUM((to_number(g.grade, '9D99') * s.subjunits)))/(SUM(s.subjunits)) AS GPA
  FROM grade g, registration r, subject s, student t
  WHERE g.grade_id = r.grade_id 
    AND g.grade NOT IN ('INC', 'INP', 'W', 'DRP')
    AND s.subjcode = r.subjcode
    AND r.studid = t.studid
    GROUP BY r.studid;`

how do you round off the gpa to the nearest hundredths?

Comment: @oshixun: You can cast the GPA to `GPA::numeric(3,2)`

Comment: ... but it's better to use `to_char` with a format-specifier.

Answer (score 2):

First, please always use `ANSI` joins. They're much more readable. That means `from x inner join y on (condition)`instead of `from x, y where condition`.

Next, I think what you want here is actually a *join* on the subqueries. It's hard to tell since you have not shown your table definitions or sample data.

I think Patrick's answer is quite right in pointing out that you do not need subqueries in this case. It's just a simple three-way inner join. If you *did* have to multiply values derived from subqueries, you would do it more like this, with subqueries in the `FROM` clause and an `INNER JOIN` to link the subqueries, then the multiplication in the `SELECT`-list.

```
SELECT 
  ng.numgrade * su.subjunits
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    r.subjcode, 
    to_number(g.grade, '9D99') AS numgrade
  FROM grade g INNER JOIN registration r ON (g.grade_id=r.grade_id )
  WHERE g.grade NOT IN ('INC', 'INP', 'W', 'DRP')
) ng
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    s.subjcode,
    s.subjunits
  FROM subject s, registration r
  WHERE s.subjcode=r.subjcode
) su
ON (su.subjcode = ng.subjcode)
```

However, in this case this is just a *hideously ugly* way of writing what Patrick wrote above. No subqueries are necessary. The only improvement I'd make on Patrick's answer is using inner joins:

```
SELECT 
  g.student_id,  -- or whatever your key is
  s.subjcode,
  (to_number(g.grade, '9D99') * s.subjunits) AS product
FROM grade g
INNER JOIN registration r ON (g.grade_id = r.grade_id)
INNER JOIN subject s ON (r.subjcode = s.subjcode)
WHERE g.grade NOT IN ('INC', 'INP', 'W', 'DRP');
```

Accept his answer, not this one.

Comment: Thanks for the thumbs-up Craig. With regards to the use of the `INNER JOIN`: it is indeed a lot harder to make a mistake because PG will throw an error on a badly formed join clause. But then again, it is also quite easy to spot a Cartesian product that is the tell-tale sign of a missing clause in a `WHERE` clause. May I call this a matter of personal preference or is there a performance benefit to using an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: @Patrick There is no performance difference. However, as you write bigger queries, old-style joins quickly become unmanagable. They're OK for simple queries, but IMO still bad style.